# Failing to call designated initialiser in NSManagedObject class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm building a simple notes app and trying to figure out how to use a custom class that I created from the data model section with editor/create NSManaged object subclass.

Since i'm a beginner, if you don't mind I will post my .m files (because its really short) just so you can catch something I didn't do right that brought this error:

Note.h: (there is nothing in the .m file, and currently i'm only dealing with the content prop)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Note : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * noteID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * content;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeCreated;

@end
```

NotesListViewController.h:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface NONotesListViewController : UITableViewController

    - (IBAction) unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

    @end

#import "NONotesListViewController.h"
#import "Note.h"
#import "NOCreateNotesViewController.h"

@interface NONotesListViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * notes;

@property NSInteger indx;

@end

@implementation NONotesListViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editeNote"]) {
        Note * selectedNote = [self.notes objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        NOCreateNotesViewController * destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        destination.note = selectedNote;
        destination.isEdited = YES;
        self.indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
    }
}


- (IBAction) unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NOCreateNotesViewController * source = [segue sourceViewController];

    Note * note = source.note;

    if (note != nil &&  source.isEdited == NO) {
        [self.notes addObject:note];
    } else {
        [self.notes replaceObjectAtIndex:self.indx withObject:note];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Note"];

    self.notes = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.notes.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    Note * note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = note.content;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

CreateNotesViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Note.h"

@interface NOCreateNotesViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Note * note;
@property BOOL isEdited;

@end
```

CreateNotesViewController.m:

```
#import "NOCreateNotesViewController.h"

@interface NOCreateNotesViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *noteText;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;

@end

@implementation NOCreateNotesViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }

    return context;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.noteText.text.length > 0) {
        self.note = [[Note alloc] init];
        self.note.content = self.noteText.text;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.isEdited) {
        [self.note setValue:self.noteText.text forKey:@"content"];
    }

    NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newNote setValue:self.noteText.text forKey:@"content"];

    NSError * error = nil;

    if ([context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:(BOOL)showKeyboard notificationInfo:(NSDictionary *)notificationInfo
{
    // the keyboard is showing so ƒ the table's height
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.noteText.frame;

    // the keyboard rect's width and height are reversed in landscape
    NSInteger adjustDelta = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect) : CGRectGetWidth(keyboardRect);

    if (showKeyboard)
    frame.size.height -= adjustDelta;
    else
    frame.size.height += adjustDelta;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.noteText.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:YES notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}


- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:NO notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `[[Note alloc] init]` because `Note` is an NSManagedObject subclass.

The designated initializer is `awakeFromInsert:` which is called after you insert the Note object in a managedObjectContext.

That gets called if you do something like this:

```
self.note = [Note [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note"
    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

See ["Creating and Deleting Managed Objects" in the Core Data Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-CJBDBHCB).

To be clear, you should not be subclassing NSManagedObject manually.  You would create an entity called Note in the xcdatamodeld file, declare that it's represented by the class Note, create a new file of the type "Core Data" which would allow Xcode to properly create the class with an `awakeFromInsert:` function prototype in it.   And if you start editing the Note class a lot, you want to look into the MOGenerator tool.  xcdatamodeld might be sufficient without having XCode create the class files for you to edit.

Comment: @stevesilva I created an entity called Note like you said that have an attribute called content and then i did editor/Create NSManagedObject subclass...thats what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  If you created the Note entity, and in the Note entity's Data Model inspector you have set the class to Note, you would then have Xcode create Note.h/.m by File->New->File->Core Data->NSManagedObject subclass.   Regardless, the crux of your issue is that you can't simply `alloc init` Note if it's a NSManagedObject subclass.